# Insert into indexed view?

Tags: sql-server, view, materialized-view

I give an example to show my problem.
I create 2 table as the following:

```
CREATE TABLE a
(
    id INT
)

CREATE TABLE b
(
    name NVARCHAR(10),
    id INT
)
```

Then insert data into these tables

```
INSERT INTO a VALUES(1),(2)
INSERT INTO b VALUES('Kan',1),('Michael',2)
```

Next,I create indexed view that join these tables via id

```
CREATE VIEW a_b
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
(
SELECT a.id,b.name FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.id=b.id
)

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX ix_a_b
ON a_b(id)

INSERT INTO a_b VALUES (3,'Joe') will be wrong
```

As I know about view:

- views do not store data,just saved queries
- but indexed view that stored data physically like table in the database.So why I don't insert,delete from a_b?

And what I know about VIEW is right or wrong?Help me improve?

Answer (score 0):

From Doc Online:

```
The view referenced by table_or_view_name must be updatable and reference exactly one base table in the FROM clause of the view. 
For example, an INSERT into a multi-table view must use a column_list that references only columns from one base table.
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15